# Firebase Functions - Return after Realtime Database fetched inside User Fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Cloud Function that is called in my app with JavaScript.
When the function is called it fetches the user data from the user ID, then fetched a record from the Realtime Database to check for a match.

This function works but is returning "null" and finishing early instead of returning the success or error message when the match is detected.

How can I make the return text be the success or error from the match and only complete once this match is decided?

```
exports.matchNumber = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
// ID String passed from the client.
const ID = data.ID;
const uid = context.auth.uid;

//Get user data
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  .then(function(userRecord) {


    // Get a database reference to our posts
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("path/to/data/" + ID);

    return ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {

        //Fetch current phone number
        var phoneORStr = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().phone) || "";

        //Fetch the current auth user phone number
        var userAuthPhoneNumber = userRecord.toJSON().phoneNumber;

        //Check if they match
        if (userAuthPhoneNumber === phoneORStr) {
            console.log("Phone numbers match");

            var updateRef = db.ref("path/to/data/" + ID);
            updateRef.update({
              "userID": uid
            });
            return {text: "Success"};
        } else {
            console.log("Phone numbers DO NOT match");
            return {text: "Phone number does not match the one on record."};
        }
    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        return {text: "Error fetching current data."};
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
    return {text: "Error fetching data for authenticated user."};
  });
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase `ref.on()` method doesn't return a promise, so the `return` statements you have in there do nothing.

You're looking for `ref.once()`, which returns a promise, and thus will bubble up the `return` statements you have within it:

```
return ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  ...
```

---

As Doug pointed out, you'll also need to return the promise from the top level. So:

```
//Get user data
return admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
```

Comment: On top of all that, they aren't even returning a value from the function at the top level.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelenThank you very much for your help!